# How can i add an image to q-button-dropdown(Quasar framework dropdown)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am creating a locale selector with vue3 and quasar, It is a dropdown that shows the current language and lets user the select a new one from the list. The problem is q-btn-dropdown does not take image as a prop(yes i read the docs btw) I do not want to use icon i need to use selectedLanguage.flag to get the current image, i have to bind it How can i do this? Here is my code so far...

````
q-btn-dropdown(color="white" :label="selectedLanguage.language" dropdown-icon="none" text-color="black")
    q-list
      q-item(v-for="(language, i) in getLanguages()" :key="i" @click="changeLocale(language.locale)" clickable v-close-popup)
        q-item-section
          q-img(:src="language.flag")
          q-item-label {{ language.language }}```
````